# Broadcasting? For loop --> numpy

Tags: python, numpy

What I have:

```
rnd_ar = np.random.randint(5, size = (10,2))
rnd_ar
array([[4, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 4],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

What I want to do is to simplify the following code by only using either numpy or pandas:

```
test = []
for i in rnd_ar:
    test.append(np.repeat(['O', 'T'],i))

test

[array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O'], dtype='<U1'),
 array([], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'O'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O'], dtype='<U1')]
```

I think the answer would be just expanding the following line:

```
np.repeat(np.array(['O', 'T']), rnd_ar[0])
```

but I am not sure what that is.

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to use broadcasting if the output is of variable size. So i guess that the list comprehension is your best solution.

Comment: `np.repeat` does mention `broadcasting` but it's a little trickier to apply than the broadcasting of operators like addition.  `broadcasting` lets us make a (m,n) shape array from (m,1) and (n,) shaped arrays.  Your desired output is nothing like that.  It's a list of arrays that vary widely in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
rnd_ar = np.random.randint(5, size = (10,2))
rnd_ar
array([[4, 3],
       [4, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 4],
       [4, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

You can use

> list comprehension

```
test = [np.repeat(['O', 'T'],i) for i in rnd_ar]
```

If you wish to do it without a `for` loop, then you can use several numpy function all together. I will do it like this:

```
np.split(
    np.repeat(np.array(['O', 'T'] * rnd_ar.shape[0]).reshape(rnd_ar.shape),
              rnd_ar.flatten()),
    np.cumsum(np.sum(rnd_ar, axis=1)))
```

The output for the above `rnd_ar` will be:

```
[array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['O', 'O', 'T'], dtype='<U1'),
 array([], dtype='<U1')]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what i meant is to apply a function (np.repeat) from 1D array onto each row of 2D array... without using for loop

Comment: @KevinChoi I think your question is not clear enough, because you explicitly ask for a for loop. I have added another solution without a for loop. Please check that out. hope this helps. I recommend to modify the question title.